# Choosing between two available packages for multinomial logit on panel data in R

Tags: r, panel-data, multinomial-distribution, multinomial-logit

There are two available packages for estimating multinomial logit models in R, namely [mnlogit](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mnlogit/mnlogit.pdf) and [mlogit](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/mlogit.pdf). I am wondering whether someone who used both can share his experience. Which one is better / more commonly used? Are there some advantages to using one of them? How do the packages deal with pannel data?

Comment: Discussion that require opinions belong at CV Meta.

Comment: @Michael Meta is *only* for discussing this site, not for any opinion-oriented discussions.  Our chat is a good place for general discussions.  In the present case, I can imagine that answers might refer to different algorithms or assumptions made by these packages and thereby could give this thread some useful statistical meaning, so I am reluctant to close it because it superficially deals with software packages.

Comment: searching on this site now, mnlogit has 7 hits, mlogit has hundreds ...